# How to update the parent / list component from the child / detail component in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I am beginner and practicing on Library Management System in react. So I have components named `BookDetails.js`, `BookList.js`. BookDetails contains the form for entering Title and Description. So How can I pass the data entered from BookDetails to BookList and to dispaly from App.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import BookList from './BookList'
const BookDetails = (props) => {
const [bookdetails, setbookDetails] = useState('')
const [desc, setDesc] = useState('')

    const titleChangehandler = (e) => {
        setbookDetails(e.target.value)

    }
    const descriptionChangehandler = (e) => {
        setDesc(e.target.value)

    }
    const submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        return (
            <div className='bookdetails'>
                <form className='form_bookdetails' onSubmit={submitHandler}>
                    <div>
                        <label>Enter Title:</label>
                        <input type='text' value={bookdetails} onChange={titleChangehandler}></input>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Enter Description:</label>
                        <input type='text' value={desc} onChange={descriptionChangehandler}></input>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button type='submit'>Add Details</button>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default BookDetails
```

BookList.js

```
import React from 'react'
import './BookList.css'
import BookDetails from './BookDetails'

const BookList = () => {


  return (
    <div className="booklist">
      <header>BookList</header>
      <BookDetails  />
    </div>

  )
}

export default BookList
```

Comment: You make use of props in react.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use props. `BookList` state will have an `update` function that it will pass to the `BookDetail` via props. Example ([CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/todo-list-edit-todo-example-zr1ud6)) with Todo with `title` & `description`.

`BookDetail` will invoke this method on every save which then would update the original list.

**TodoList.js**

```
export default function TodoList() {
  const [todo, setTodo] = React.useState(null);
  const [todoList, setTodoList] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getTodos();
  }, []);

  function getTodos() {
    console.log("===> fetch all todos!!");
    fetchTodos().then((todos) => {
      setTodoList(todos);
    });
  }

  function editTodo(todo) {
    console.log("===> set todo => ", todo);
    setTodo(todo);
  }

  function handleUpdate(updatedTodo) {
    // update Todo
    const updatedTodos = todoList.map((el) =>
      el.id === updatedTodo.id ? updatedTodo : el
    );
    setTodoList(updatedTodos);
    setTodo(null);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {todoList.map((item) => (
          <li key={item.id}>
            {item.title}, {item.description}
            <button onClick={() => editTodo(item)}>edit</button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      {todo && <TodoDetail todo={todo} updateTodo={handleUpdate} />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**TodoDetail.js**

```
import React from "react";

export default function TodoDetail(props) {
  const [todo, setTodo] = React.useState(props.todo);
  console.log("todo =>", todo);
  function handleChange(key, value) {
    console.log("===> todo changed!");
    setTodo({
      ...todo,
      [key]: value
    });
  }

  function handleSubmit() {
    // api PUT on todo
    console.log("===> todo edit submit!!");
    props.updateTodo(todo);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="title">
          <input
            value={todo.title}
            onChange={(e) => handleChange("title", e.target.value)}
          />
          <input
            value={todo.description}
            onChange={(e) => handleChange("description", e.target.value)}
          />
        </label>
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: i have added these code in booklist and still it show me warning as "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop" and still i cannot get display value.help
``` const BookList = () => {
  const [bookList, setBookList] = useState([])

  const addBook = (book) => {
    setBookList([...bookList, book])

  }
  const Display=()=>{
    return (
      <ul>
      {bookList.map((list) => (
          <li key={list}>{list}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }```

Comment: @SudipGiri It's a warning. If you see my answer `<li key={item.id}>`, every `li` has a unique prop. This should fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the list of books in your BookList component like

```
const [bookList, setBookList] = useState([])
```

This way your BookList component has access to the books. You can then create a function to add books to the list

```
  function addBook(book) {
     setBookList([...bookList, book])
  }
```

Then pass the `addBook()` function to the BookDetails component to use it on submit.

```
<BookDetails addBook={addBook}
```

Now BookDetails can access the function as a prop

```
props.addBook("pass new book here")
```

Comment: `const Display=()=>{
    return (
      <ul>
      {bookList.map((list) => (
          <li key={list}>{list}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  } `It shows me an error as Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop for the above code. could you please help to remove this

Comment: @SudipGiri   the key needs to be unique for each item. So you can assign the key for each item to be equivalent to its index in the list. To achieve this, you can add a second parameter to the map function bookList.map((list, index)=>{}). The index will hold a unique integer for every item and so you can use it as the key.